# Upload an image to a folder in python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, file-upload, filedialog

Does anybody know how to upload an image (using **filedialog.askopenfile**) and then storing the uploaded image to an existing folder on my computer?! All the examples available on the internet require image paths, and i get an error whenever i provide the filepath for the uploaded image, am i doing something wrong?

```
import cv2
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
filename = askopenfile(title ='open', filetypes=(("PNGs", "*.png"),("JPGs", "*.jpg"), ("GIFs", "*.gif")))

img = cv2.imread(filename)
path = "/Users/mac/desktop/test" # => Folder path
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, img)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you please post the full traceback so that we can debug it

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `askopenfile` and `askopenfilename`?

Comment: @BryanOakley I did a quick search and it seems like "askopenfilename" returns the path to the selected file, which is what i'm looking for. Should i use it in this case?

Comment: @TheLizzard The error i'm getting is: SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: If you want the file path, then yes, the function that returns the path is the one you should use.

Comment: Use `filedialog.askopenfilename` not `askopenfile` it returns and `io.TextIOWrapper`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks a lot but I'm still getting an error that says: `join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'ndarray'` am i storing the image incorrectly?

Comment: `img` is not a string, so you can't join it to a string. That's what the error is telling you. If you're trying to create a fully qualified path, you need to join the folder path and the filename, not the folder path and the image data.

Comment: @BryanOakley I changed it to `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, filename))` and now it gives me the error `TypeError: imwrite() missing required argument 'img' (pos 2)`

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for the `imwrite` method.

Comment: Yes i figured out the problem from reading the documentation, thank you!